# Unarchiving iOS4 data on iOS5 doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios5, nscoding

I've archived an `NSDictionary` on iOS 4 using an `NSKeyedArchiver`, but unarchiving on iOS 5 using

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data]
```

throws this exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]:
incomprehensible archive (0x62, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x30, 0x30)'
```

Note that unarchiving on iOS 4 works fine.  `plutil -lint` reports that the archive is okay.  Here it is, for reference:

http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/schani/monkeyfull.ltg